Replacing old style 2 way switch with a new style
Trying to replace a faulty 2way light switch one of the switches no longer works in kitchen with a new style. Terminology is completely different and would like a steer how to rewire as Screwfix, Homebase haven't a clue.
Included the current wiring layout and the new one.
Help would be gratefully received.
Thanks

It’s pretty simple, actually.
COM on the old switch goes to COMMON on the new.
L1 on the old goes to 1WAY on the new.
L2 on the old goes to 2WAY on the new.
(The clue is the note on the old switch “1WAY USE Ll”.)
Don’t forget to keep the wires on each side (individual switch) separate and on the same Sade as the old one.

Note that in the original switch, the right switch (as seen from the back) is upsides down (common is to the bottom); in the replacement the two switches are the same way up (common is to the top)
